# Execution order in Google Sheet - App Script vs in cell functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, execution

I can't find info on script execution order when App Scripts and in cell functions are intertwined. Let me explain my situation...

I have a sheet with over 30000 rows of part numbers and I'm looking through it to see if a part number exists in there. Using a MATCH() function within a cell is lightning fast, but only tells me if the part is in there, not what row it's in. That's fine, I use it and IF it finds it, I use a textfinder in my App Script to get the specifics of where it is in the sheet.

The code below works. I repeat it works. But I'm worried that it won't always, because as you can see, the lookUpPart() function starts, it sets a cell value, then the in cell MATCH() fires, then the rest of lookUpPart() function happens.

I just want to know if this script execution order is sustainable, or is it a fluke that it's working this way? Can I expect this to always work in the order it is?

```
function lookUpPart(){
  // for testing, this line sets A1 to the part number I'm searching for
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue("818174-L21");

  // the MATCH() function in the cell sets B1 to true if the part# in A1 is found
  // so in the middle of this function, the in cell function below IS happening
  // =IF(MATCH(A1,A3:A30150,0)>=1,"true","false")

  // then if B1 is true, do a text finder to find the exact row
  if(sheet.getRange('B1').getValue() == 'true'){
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var foundName = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow, 1).createTextFinder(sheet.getRange('A1').getValue()).matchCase(false).findNext();
    var description = sheet.getRange(foundName.getRow(), 6).getValue();
  }
}
```

Again, this works currently. I just find it odd that in the middle of an App Script function it is waiting for an in-cell function to fire. I get the execution order if I call a 2nd function from within a 1st function, but I'm not technically calling the in-cell function here, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it'll work all the time. Do note that sheets is a cloud resource, a database in Google cloud. Whenever you `set`, you essentially make a call to a external Google sheets server. When you `get`, you get data from that server. When you `set`, that external server does all the calculations and makes new data ready.

Having said that, Google uses caching to not make a extra call. Because you alternate `set` and `get`, it has to make two calls, because any cache would be invalid after a `set`. As written in the [best practices of the official guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations),

> Google Apps Script already has some built-in optimization, such as using look-ahead caching to retrieve what a script is likely to get and write caching to save what is likely to be set.

If you want to be sure you invalidated any cache, you can use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.

However, the entire strategy is very slow compared to doing it all inside the script. The efficient method is `get` data, check if  something is present inside the script and `set` the data. The fastest however would be doing it all inside formula. Are you looking for `INDEX/MATCH`?

Comment: No I'm a dope. I had been writing the code one way, then started adding App Script on top of it and just brainfarted with what was already in my sheet vs simply using MATCH to get my row number.

I still find it interesting that it executed as expected.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ChrisSheeler https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match